# Sabre EnhancedAirBookRS CHECK SEGMENT 0003 error

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap, sabre

i'm trying to Book a flight CCS-SYD with an infant (INF)

This is the Request i sent to EnhancedAirBookRS

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ
        xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7" version="3.7.0" HaltOnError="false">
        <OTA_AirBookRQ>
            <RetryRebook Option="true"/>
            <HaltOnStatus Code="UC"/>
            <HaltOnStatus Code="LL"/>
            <HaltOnStatus Code="UN"/>
            <HaltOnStatus Code="NO"/>
            <HaltOnStatus Code="HL"/>
            <HaltOnStatus Code="NN"/>
            <OriginDestinationInformation>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-06-21T19:55:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-06-21T18:35:00" FlightNumber="81" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="81" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-06-22T14:31:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-06-22T07:36:00" FlightNumber="115" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="SCL" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="115" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-06-24T09:10:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-06-23T00:05:00" FlightNumber="322" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="N" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="SYD" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="LA" FlightNumber="322" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="SCL" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-06-30T11:10:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-06-30T12:30:00" FlightNumber="27" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="N" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="SCL" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="QF" FlightNumber="27" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="SYD" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-06-30T20:23:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-06-30T15:16:00" FlightNumber="116" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="116" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="SCL" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-07-01T11:07:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-07-01T08:08:00" FlightNumber="66" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="K" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="66" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
            <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="5" WaitInterval="2000"/>
        </OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
            <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
                <OptionalQualifiers>
                    <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="USD">
                        <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="2" />
                        <PassengerType Code="INF" Quantity="1" />
                    </PricingQualifiers>
                </OptionalQualifiers>
            </PriceRequestInformation>
        </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
            <RedisplayReservation WaitInterval="500"/>
        </PostProcessing>
        <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false"/>
    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

This is the answer i got:

```
<EnhancedAirBookRS
        xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7">
        <ApplicationResults
            xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
            <Success timeStamp="2017-04-21T09:46:43.599-05:00"/>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-21T09:46:40.626-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">SYSTEM UNABLE TO PROCESS</Message>
                    <Message code="0118">SYSTEM UNABLE TO PROCESS</Message>
                    <Message code="0101">INVALID OFF POINT</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-21T09:46:43.051-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">FORMAT, CHECK SEGMENT NUMBER-0003</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
        </ApplicationResults>
        <TravelItineraryReadRS>
            <TravelItinerary>
                <CustomerInfo/>
                <ItineraryInfo>
                    <ReservationItems/>
                </ItineraryInfo>
                <ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">
                    <Source PseudoCityCode="4Q0H"/>
                </ItineraryRef>
            </TravelItinerary>
        </TravelItineraryReadRS>
    </EnhancedAirBookRS>
```

i can see two errors here **INVALID OFF POINT**, **FORMAT, CHECK SEGMENT NUMBER-0003** But i cant see any weird or bad in segment 3, anybody can help??

Answer (score 1):

I believe the third segment (SCL-SYD) is actually marketed by QF and not LA. 
Since the booking failed, you ended up with no itinerary and thus, when the system tried to price your itin, it returned the FORMAT error.

If you got this whole trip from a shopping serve like BFM, I'd advise you to run the RQ again to see if it's still available.

Comment: Thankyou brother... I have a problem i was passing OperatingAriline Code instead of MarketingAirline Code.